# Which version of spring doc open ui gradle plugin be used with spring-boot 2.6?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, springdoc-openapi-ui

Which version of spring doc open ui gradle plugin be used with spring-boot 2.6 ?
I see this is the last plugin  id "org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin" version "1.3.3" which si not compatable with spring-boot 2.6

Comment: What exact issue are you facing with this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the plugin. So maybe my answer can help you...
I just migrated from Spring-Boot 2.5.4 to 2.6.7 and everything now is working properly.
I also migrated from SpringFox to OpenApi 3 using the lib org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.8

This is the class (kotlin) i used to instruct OpenApi to generate the swagger:

```
package br.com.rss.config

import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Components
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Contact
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Info
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityRequirement
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityScheme
import org.springdoc.core.GroupedOpenApi
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration

@Configuration
class OpenApiConfig {

@Bean
fun publicApi(): GroupedOpenApi? {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
        .group("1. public-apis")
        .displayName("Native Services API")
        .packagesToScan("br.com.rss.api")
        .packagesToExclude("br.com.rss.external.api")
        .pathsToMatch("/**")
        .pathsToExclude("/actuator/**")
        .build()
}

@Bean
fun externalApi(): GroupedOpenApi? {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
        .group("2. external-apis")
        .displayName("External Services API")
        .packagesToScan("br.com.rss.external.api")
        .packagesToExclude("br.com.rss.api")
        .pathsToMatch("/**")
        .pathsToExclude("/actuator/**")
        .build()
}

@Bean
fun springOpenAPI(): OpenAPI? {
    return OpenAPI()
        .addSecurityItem(SecurityRequirement().addList("bearerAuth"))
        .components(
            Components()
                .addSecuritySchemes("bearerAuth",
                SecurityScheme()
                    .name("bearerAuth")
                    .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                    .scheme("bearer")
                    .bearerFormat("JWT"))
        )
        .info(
            Info()
                .title("Open Services API")
                .description("APIs related to backend services")
                .contact(Contact().name("Thiago Rodrigues").email("thiagotrss@gmail.com"))
        )
}
}
```